# connect to analysis services from excel 2007 on windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, excel-2007

Is it possible to connect to an Analysis Services Database (2008) from Excel 2007 on Windows 7?

I have installed the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services 10.0 OLE DB Provider" but it's not possible to create a connection.

It works on windows XP and on Windows Vista so I guess the problem is Windows 7?

Comment: It works on a second computer - maybe I installed things in a different order...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found out what my specific problem was. (At least this problem is what is still true - I think some update from microsoft has taken care of part of the problem)

I had excel workbooks created with Excel 2003.

When opened in Excel 2007 on Win7 the pivot tables were not able to connect to SSAS.

The solution was to change the connections for each pivot table to a new connection created in excel 2007.

So in conclusion there seems to be some difference in how connections to ssas was created between the two versions and for some reason it didn't affect winXP.